# How to define types for shared screens in the react-navigation stack navigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

If I have two stack navigators which have the same screen, how can I define typescript types for that screen?

If it belongs in only one navigator I would put something like this:

```
export interface SharedScreenProps {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<
    FirstNavigatorParams,
    'Shared screen'
  >;
  route: RouteProp<FirstNavigatorParams, 'Shared screen'>;
}
```

Both stack navigators have their own routes that this screen can take and they don't have anything in common.
Now when I have the second stack navigator I can make the types working. There is `CompositeNavigationProp` but it isn't that much of a help and it does not suit this use case.
Thank you.